# Converting "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" to Seconds Since Midnight

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

When a cell only has the time, it is a trivial multiplication by 86400 to get seconds since midnight. I don't know how to communicate to excel that I don't need any information about the date.

Comment: So you have a cell containing date in `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM` and want excel to convert it to seconds since midnight?

Answer (score 3):

As you say that multiplying by 86400 will get you seconds since midnight, I assume that the cell contains a datetime value formatted as "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM".

Excel's datetime values are numbers where the integer part represents the date and the fractional part represents the time. To ignore the date, all you need to do is remove the integer part before multiplying. For example, if the datetime is in cell A1:

```
=(A1-INT(A1))*86400
```

`INT(A1)` is the integer part of the number. Subtracting it from A1 leaves the fractional part, which you can multiply by 86400 to convert it to seconds. That answer may still include fractions of a second. If you want to get rid of those fractions so you have a whole number of seconds, wrap the whole statement in another `INT` function.

```
=INT((A1-INT(A1))*86400)
```